# My application is trying to hijack my own application?

Tags: iphone, uikit, ios-simulator, ios4

I'm developing a iPhone application and until now not big problems. But today I had a weird problem. When I run my application in the simulator, everything works fine. But when I run my application on my iPhone 3GS I get a SIGABRT signal in the XCode and the following message on the console of my device:

```
Sat Aug 28 12:00:56 Peters-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] 
(UIKitApplication:com.peter.picturecallinglite[0x68ac]) <Warning>: 
(UIKitApplication:com.peter.picturecallinglite[0x68ac]) 
The following job tried to hijack the service "com.peter.picturecallinglite" 
from this job: UIKitApplication:com.peter.picturecallinglite[0xcda6]
```

But if I understand this correctly, I'm hijacking my own application? What does this mean? And why is this not a problem in the simulator? And what kind of statements can created this error?

Comment: You should post more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try to reboot my iPhone. After that everything worked again.

Thanks for the time anyway.